# Одновременная передача переменных и значений формы

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой передачи переменных и значений форм, причем все одновременно
Вот скрипт:

```
<form method="post" action="InsDateTB.php">
<?php

$Table=strip_tags($_GET["table"]);
$selDB=strip_tags($_GET["selDB"]);

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','12345');
  mysql_select_db($selDB);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM $Table";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$connect) or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());

    $i=1;
    print "<table>";
        print "<tr>";
    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {

    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result,$i);
     print "<td>";
     print "Поле: $field->name<br>Тип: $field->type<br><input name='$field->name' type='text'>";
     print "</td>";   
    $i++;
    }
        print "</tr>";
    print "</table>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

На страницу указанную в action - InsDateTB.php - нужно передать не только значения введенные в поля ввода, но и значения переменных $Table и $selDB... Знаю что переменные можно передать таким образом:

```
print "<a href='InsTB.php?table=$Table&selDB=$selDB'>Добавить данные</a>";
```

но как это совместить с нажатием одной кнопки?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте hidden-поля

```
<input type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value="la-la" />
```

**UPD**

А вообще ваш код - полная жуть. Тут не только каша, но и очень опасные манипуляции с данными из параметров. Любой желающий может уничтожить всю базу данных как только пожелает ;)

Comment: Оу, хорошо... к примеру так будет print "<input type='hidden' name='table' value='$Table'/>"; ?..

Comment: Вы великий критик cy6erGn0m;)..)) Где именно каша? И в чем опасность?) Буду оч благодарен если подскажите)

Comment: Кашей является ведь этот код :) У вас чтение из базы, итерация и прочее смешаны с выводом документа.. это выглядит чудовищно.. тут фетч, тут же print с HTML-ем.. тут же какой-то i++.. вдург одинокая скобка.. не читается вообще. <br/>

Опасность в том, что пользователь может подставить вам в качестве параметра table целую строку... например, я бы подставил что-то типа table=myTable%20UNION%20TRUNCATE%20%TABLE%20users и тогда вся таблица с пользователями (например) будет уничтожена. Это называется SQL Injection.

Comment: object mysql_fetch_field ( resource result [, int field_offset] ) - Возвращает объект, содержащий информацию о колонке. $i=1; ..
    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result,$i);
    ... обрабатываем информацию о колонке по номером i
    echo "$field->name"; 
    $i++;
    } скобки тут  нет одинокой

Comment: Но выглядит это так.. неудобно эти скобки отслеживать, когда такое творится. Да и читать\модифицировать HTML-код внутри скобок неудобно. В общем, "грусть и печаль в русских поселениях.."

Comment: Ну а так то все выполняется по порядку.. И нагромождений больших нет, скрипт простой... Если есть лучший вариант решения этой задачи, то подскажите, если можете) А вот на счет SQL Injection эт да, я не продумал... Спасибо;)

Comment: Лучший вариант? Запросто. Используйте шаблонизаторы и будет всё аккуратно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы про совмещение передачи посредством POST и GET одновременно то можно использовать action=smth.php?.... в теге формы, естественно вам придется парсить массивы POST и GET в файле smth.php
Можно также использовать input type=hidden.
в обоих вариантах значения переменных пользователь легко может получить